# V-sync won't disable in android build

Tags: android, performance, unity-game-engine, profiler, vsync

As the title suggests I am having issues with v-sync on android. I've set the v sync Count to `Don't sync` in the qualitySettings panel for the used quality level. However when i run my application on the samsung galaxy S6 its having a constant fps of ~15 due to waiting on vsync to happen (where it is ~60 fps with some spikes to 30 without v-sync).

profiler with v-sync tracked: [image] 
profiler without v-sync tracked: [image]

As you can see it is crealy caused by v-sync happening. What i find strangest about this is that this only started happening a couple of days ago, and was working fine before. Even going back to a commit that 100% worked before v-sync starts messing it up.

I'm using Unity 2017.2.1f1. And have not done any updates to my android version.

Could this be caused by my phone forcing v-sync in some way (or is it happening becuase it is in VR using a samsung gear? and if it is can i turn that off somehwere?

EDIT: Running my application in the editor doesn't have the issue and V-sync doesn't happen at all, neither does it try to v-sync when i'm running the application on a onePlus 3 in non-vr